# Alloy UI Textarea not working Properly

Tags: javascript, html, alloy-ui

I am trying to append HTML Content in Alloy Input Textarea. It is working fine. But when I try to delete the Textarea content and again try to append content it shows nothing. I show in Developer Console that data is appended there.

I am appending data on OnChange Event of Option Element

```
function onchangeCall(){
    AUI().use('node', function(A) {
        var agendaData = A.one("#<portlet:namespace/>meetingagenda").html();
        var contactKey = A.one("#<portlet:namespace/>contactDetailOption option:checked").get("text");
        var contactValue = A.one("#<portlet:namespace/>contactDetailOption").val();
        A.one("#<portlet:namespace/>meetingagenda").html("");
        A.one("#<portlet:namespace/>meetingagenda").html(agendaData);
        A.one("#<portlet:namespace/>meetingagenda").append(contactKey+" "+contactValue);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working perfectly now.

```
function onchangeCall(){
    AUI().use('node', function(A) {
        var agendaData = A.one("#<portlet:namespace/>meetingagenda").val();
        var contactKey = A.one("#<portlet:namespace/>contactDetailOption option:checked").get("text");
        var contactValue = A.one("#<portlet:namespace/>contactDetailOption").val();
        if(agendaData == ""){
            A.one("#<portlet:namespace/>meetingagenda").val(contactKey+" "+contactValue);
        }
        else{
            A.one("#<portlet:namespace/>meetingagenda").val(agendaData+"\n"+contactKey+" "+contactValue);           
        }
    });
}
```